# JQuery - Remove class

Tags: jquery

I had already a close look to the search, but was not able to find a specific solution for my problem. I have the follow code:

```
    $('.filter li a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    var $this = $(this).parent();

    if($this.hasClass('active')) {
        return;
    }

    $self.closest('ul').children().removeClass('active');
    $self.parent().addClass('active');

    $container.shuffle( 'shuffle', $this.data('group') );
});
```

I want now to remove this line:

```
$self.closest('ul').children().removeClass('active');
```

Aim should be, that I can select multiple items and not just one with the class "active".
Any ideas?

Many thanks.

To be more clear here a small image how the menu looks:
[image: Menu]

The visitor comes to page and the point "Show All" is marked.
Noe he should be able to select from the four options "A3, A4, Farbe, S/W". With the current code it's just possible to choose one at the same time. But I would need to be able to choose more at the same time.

And here the HTML code:

```
<div class="filter">
        <ul>
            <li class="active" data-group="all"><a href="#">Show All</a></li>
                                        <li data-group="a3" class=""><a href="#">A3</a></li>
                                                <li data-group="a4" class=""><a href="#">A4</a></li>
                                                <li data-group="farbe" class=""><a href="#">Farbe</a></li>
                                                <li data-group="s-w" class=""><a href="#">S/W</a></li>
                                </ul>
    </div>
```

Added 17/03/2016:
There are 5 menu points. The first one is "Show all". When one of the other 4 points (A3,A4,Farbe,S/W) is clicked, the first one (Show all) should loose the class "active" and the one new clicked should get the class "active". If again "Show all" is clicked, only this menu point should have the class "active".

Each menu point has also a data-group. The point "Show-All" has the data-group="all". So if this menu point is clicked, only this data-group should be active. If the menu point "A3" is clicked, the data-group="A3" should be active. If also "A4" is clicked, than also this data-group should be active. Same way, if "A4" is clicked again, the class="active" should be removed as well as the data-group="A4". And when "Show all" is clicked again, all data-groups should be removed and only the data-group="all" should be active.

Answer (score 0):

A user "usually" expects multiple entries to be selected when they hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, so you could modify that line to this:

```
if (!event.shiftKey) {
  $self.closest('ul').children().removeClass('active');
}
```

So now you will still select one item at a time, until you hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the solution with the shift key is not an option, as this code is used on a menu on the homepage. And on mobile version the user don't have a shift key.

Answer (score 0):

So if you do not want to remove all the classes, than just toggle it on the current on that is clicked.

```js
$('.filter li a').on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
  <ul>
    <li class="active" data-group="all"><a href="#">Show All</a></li>
    <li data-group="a3" class=""><a href="#">A3</a></li>
    <li data-group="a4" class=""><a href="#">A4</a></li>
    <li data-group="farbe" class=""><a href="#">Farbe</a></li>
    <li data-group="s-w" class=""><a href="#">S/W</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this is working in case of adding the class active. But I got problems with the data-group. I have edited my first post to be more clear.

Comment: So add a code to see to the item is show all, if not, than remove the selection...